# 'title' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

After updating my models and serializers, I cannot save new articles to the Database. I keep getting *"'title' is an invalid keyword argument for this function."*

I am working on Postgres10, Python3.6, Django2.0 and DRF 3.8.2.

I have dropped my DB a couple of times but the error persists. Please, I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Here's a copy of my old models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='created')
    body = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) 
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, default=1)
    # categories = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), blank=False)
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, default=1)
    # entities = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), 
    blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_curated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My new (updated) models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='created')
    body = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True) 
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="posts")
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default=1, related_name="posts")
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, default=1, 
    related_name="posts")
    summary = models.TextField()
    keypoint1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, 
    null=False)
    keypoint2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, 
    null=False)
    keypoint3 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True,  
    null=True)
    keypoint4 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_curated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My serializers:

```
class CreateArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    country = CountrySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("id", "title", "body", "image_url", "country", 
        "keypoint1", "keypoint2", "keypoint3", "keypoint4", 
        "category", "entities", "author", "created", "updated", 
        "published", "is_published")
        read_only_fields = ("id", "created", "slug")

    def create(self, validated_data):

        entities_relations = validated_data.pop('entities', None)
        entity_instance = Entity.objects.create(**validated_data)
        entity_instance.posts = entities_relations
        article = Article.objects.create(entities=entity_instance, 
        **validated_data)


        return article
```

And my create post view:

```
class ArticleAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    #Create a new post
    def post(self, request, format=None):


        data_map = {
          'title': request.data.get('title'),
          'body': request.data.get('body'),
          'image_url': request.data.get('imageUrl'),
          'keypoint1': request.data.get('keyPoint1'),
          'keypoint2': request.data.get('keyPoint2'),
          'keypoint3': request.data.get('keyPoint3'),
          'keypoint4': request.data.get('keyPoint4'),
        }

        serializer = CreateArticleSerializer(data=data_map,context= 
        {'request': request})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
            post_id = serializer.instance.id
            post = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=post_id)
            return Response((jsend.success({'post': 
                serializer.data})), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            return Response((jsend.fail(serializer.errors)), 
               status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the create method of the serializer you are trying to create an `Entity` with the data fields of an `Article`:

```
    entities_relations = validated_data.pop('entities', None)
    entity_instance = Entity.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

You didn't specify the line where the error occurs, but it seems to be here. I don't know the fields of the `Entity` model, but title seems to not be one of them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's it. You just saved me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about

```
entity_instance = Entity.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

??
Is the Entity model accepting the same fields of the Article one?

Comment: No it isn't. Thanks for your answer. Problem solved.